# Incorrect table array

Tags: tables

I want to build a table like this:

[image]

I have tried a code but it doesn't work properly:

```
  \begin{table}[htp]
\caption{The temporal outlier detection accuracy of hourly mean values with respect to the Mos in 2007-09-30}
    \label{tab:todh30}
            \centering
                \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Node ID   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Density-based} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Mahalanobis distance-based}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Running average-based} \\ 
    & DR\%  &  FPR\%     & DR\%  &  FPR\%      & DR\%  &  FPR\% \\ \hline
25   & 100    & 14            & 100    & 14           & 66   & 20      \\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: You got too many  `\\\`.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides, I have tried the code by omitting the two first "\\" of each row. Still it doesn't appear properly.

Comment: Please post a minimal with only one line of data with corrections.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides The question is updated.

Comment: @HarishKumar It is updated, but there is problem with first row.

Comment: Still you have many `\cline{2-3}`. Put only one `\cline{2-7}` at the end and remove others. Also why so many `|c|`s. It is enough to have `\begin{tabular}{|c|*6{r|}}`. Also put `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{DR\%}` in the second row for all to center them.

Answer (score 1):

You had too many mistakes with `\\`, `\cline` and `\hline` try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]
  \centering
  \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Node ID   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Density-based} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Mahalanobis distance-based}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Running average-based} \\ 
\cline{2-7} 
     & DR\%   &  FPR\%      & DR\%   &  FPR\%     & DR\%   &  FPR\% \\ \hline 
25   & 100    & 71          & 100    & 71         & 100    & 60      \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Also it is always easier to post a full MWe including `documentclass` etc, as I did.

Comment: The line below the running average and Mahalanobis-distance and Density-based is missed.

Comment: Prints fine on my computer. Try adding some more data and getting a bit more familiar with tables.

Comment: I have updated the question, and new problem.